# How to handle std::vector<...>::size_type being int

Tags: c++, types

I have two vectors:

```
std::vector<const A> v_a;
std::vector<B> v_b;
```

during the program `v_a` is filled with values.
Now i want to transform the values of type `A` into `B` and fill `v_b`.

I start by resizing `v_b`, please note that std::transform ist not working for me:

```
v_b.resize(v_a.size());        // Auto-construct new elements using default c-tor
```

This leads to the following warning:

```
Value Conversion Issue
-Wsign-conversion
202:55: warning: implicit conversion changes signedness: 'std::vector<const A, std::allocator<const A> >::size_type' (aka 'int') to 'std::vector<B, std::allocator<B> >::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long long')
```

How is it possible that a vectors size_type is int, it should at least be an unsigned?

How is it possible that two vectors have different size_types? Even if they are defined in different source files the compiler should use the same type.
Is it possible to modify the size_type?

How can i (safely) check if `v_a.size() < v_b.max_size()` without producing new warnings?

---

The QT-Creator states that i use "Microsof Visual C++ Compiler 15.0 (amd64)" as compiler.

Comment: could you provide a minimal and reproducible example?

Comment: Without a [mcve] I am inclined to write this question off as fiction.   `std::vector::size_type` is specified by the standard as being an unsigned type, and it is difficult to imagine any implementation having signed and unsigned specialisations.

Comment: Sounds like a bug of the implementation.

Comment: `std::vector<const A ...` looks suspicious. C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because `allocator<const T>` is ill-formed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [L. F.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56272851/7617604) for answering the questions.

The real problem, as AMA pointed out, is the use of `const` in the type parameter of `v_a`. This lead to a compiler-error and ultimately to the warning stated in my question.

The solution was to remove the const-qualifier and fix the dependent types.

Answer (score 6):

> How is it possible that a `vector`'s `size_type` is `int`, it should
>   at least be an unsigned?

This is a problem with the implementation. Per [[container.requirements.general]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements), `X::size_type` is an unsigned integer type, where `X` is a Container. A `vector` is a Container.

> How is it possible that two `vector`s have different `size_type`s?
>   Even if they are defined in different source files the compiler should
>   use the same type.

Not exactly. Two `vector`s (with different element types or allocator types) are free to have different `size_type`s, as long as they are unsigned integer types and can represent any non-negative value of the corresponding `difference_type`.

> Is it possible to modify the `size_type`?

No. You cannot directly change the library.

> How can I (safely) check if `v_a.size() < v_b.max_size()` without
>   producing new warnings?

For your current situation, you can use a cast as a workaround.

```
v_b.resize(static_cast<std::vector<B>::size_type>(v_a.size()));
```

Again, this is a bug of the implementation anyway, and it is not your fault.

Comment: vectors of the same type should also have the same `size_type`, no?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yes. On the other hand, `vector<A>` and `vector<B>` are not the same type.

Comment: you cannot know unless `A` is not the same as `B` ;). Often you really dont know if two tpyes are actually the same (unless you check explicitly). Anyhow, I am just nitpicking and suggest to change "Two vectors are free to have different" to "Two vectors of different type ..."

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Let's go further to include "different element type or allocator type" ;-)

Comment: thats exactly what i meant. A vector with a different element type is a vector of different type